# Double the letter and put 'o' in betwwen if letter in a string is a consonant, otherwise not

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to solve a problem that requires me to take a sentence and double each consonant and put an 'o' in between.

I know that it's possible to use an if statement in one line but the 'else' statement doesn't work.

```
vowels = list('aeiouyäöå')
consonants = list('qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm')


# if letter is a consonant then double it and out 'o' in between.
def rovarspraket(sentence):
    return ''.join([letter for letter in sentence if letter in vowels else (letter + 'o' + letter)])

print(rovarspraket('hello friend'))
# should output 'hohelollolo fofrorienondod'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax for the else-part in the conditional comprehension a bit  wrong:

```
def rovarspraket(sentence):
    return ''.join([l if l in vowels else (l + 'o' + l) for l in sentence])
```

Or even better (more robust wrt whitespace):

```
def rovarspraket(sentence):
    return ''.join([(l + 'o' + l) if l in consonants else l for l in sentence])

>>> print(rovarspraket('hello friend'))
hohelollolo fofrorienondod
```

Answer (score 0):

The space matters too:

```
return ''.join(letter if letter in vowels or letter == ' ' else (letter + 'o' + letter)for letter in sentence)
```

So whole, code:

```
vowels = list('aeiouyäöå')
consonants = list('qwrtpsdfghjklzxcvbnm')


# if letter is a consonant then double it and out 'o' in between.
def rovarspraket(sentence):
    return ''.join(letter if letter in vowels or letter == ' ' else (letter + 'o' + letter)for letter in sentence)

print(rovarspraket('hello friend'))
```

Output:

```
hohelollolo fofrorienondod
```